# CREATE TABLE SAS

Tags: oracle

No sé que es lo que hay de malo en mi sentencia, no me crea la tabla, la linea de código es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE CONTRAP AS
    SELECT OPERACION_DIRECTO.TRAN_NUM,
           OPERACION_DIRECTO.INTERNAL_LENTITY,
           OPERACION_DIRECTO.EXTERNAL_BUNIT,
           OPERACION_DIRECTO.EXTERNAL_LENTITY,
           CONTRAPARTE_LEGAL.PARTY_ID AS PARTY_ID
      FROM OPERACION_DIRECTO INNER JOIN FINDURDG.LEGAL_ENTITY CONTRAPARTE_LEGAL
        ON OPERACION_DIRECTO.INTERNAL_LENTITY=CONTRAPARTE_LEGAL.PARTY_ID;
```

Los errores que le preceden:

> Unresolved reference to table/correlation name CONTRAP

Answer (score 0):

Intenta realizarlo de este modo, solo le cambie los nombre de los alias sin utilizar los nombres de las tablas

```
CREATE TABLE CONTRAP AS
        SELECT a.TRAN_NUM,
               a.INTERNAL_LENTITY,
               a.EXTERNAL_BUNIT,
               a.EXTERNAL_LENTITY,
               b.PARTY_ID
          FROM OPERACION_DIRECTO a 
          INNER JOIN LEGAL_ENTITY b ON a.INTERNAL_LENTITY=b.PARTY_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Has puesto el PROC?

En SAS debería ser:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE CONTRAP AS
    SELECT OPERACION_DIRECTO.TRAN_NUM,
           OPERACION_DIRECTO.INTERNAL_LENTITY,
           OPERACION_DIRECTO.EXTERNAL_BUNIT,
           OPERACION_DIRECTO.EXTERNAL_LENTITY,
           CONTRAPARTE_LEGAL.PARTY_ID AS PARTY_ID
      FROM OPERACION_DIRECTO INNER JOIN FINDURDG.LEGAL_ENTITY CONTRAPARTE_LEGAL
        ON OPERACION_DIRECTO.INTERNAL_LENTITY=CONTRAPARTE_LEGAL.PARTY_ID;

QUIT;
```